# How could I change this to a for loop?

Tags: python

I don't understand inner workings of dictionary comprehension loop. How could I change this to a `for` loop?

```
s_f={node:-1 for node in adj_list.keys()}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/ this might help you.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation.

Comment: Why is `adj_list` called that when it's a dict?

Answer (score 1):

It's equivalent to this:

```
s_f = {}
for node in ajd_list.keys():
    s_f[node] = -1
```

A dictionary comprehension is equivalent to assigning to the key of the resulting dictionary each time through the loop, just as a list comprehension is equivalent to calling `append()` on the resulting list in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```py
s_f={node:-1 for node in adj_list.keys()}
```

is the same as

```py
sf = {}
for node in adj_list.keys():
    sf[node] = -1
```

keep in mind that comprehension is usually faster than a for loop, especially with large data.